# How to say "I can't wait"

Tags: sentence-structure, word-order

I'm confused about word order and sentence structure when using phrases like `I can't wait`.

For example, is *I can't wait to come to the cinema.*:

> Ich kann's kaum erwarten zu kommen ins Kino.

or

> Ich kann's kaum erwarten, zu ins Kino kommen.

Or something else? How do you add a phrase like `to come to the cinema` after a main verb. Also, how would you use this in, for example, perfect tense? (Would it be `Ich habe es kaum erwarten können, zu ins Kino kommen`?) Another example of this is `have been`, as in *I have been singing lots of songs.* Would that be

> Ich habe gewesen, zu viele Lieder singen.

And finally, why is the `es` used in `Ich kann es kaum erwarten`? Why is it not sufficient to use `Ich kann kaum erwarten`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your examples are wrong.

> Ich kann es kaum erwarten, ins Kino zu kommen.
>
> Ich konnte es kaum erwarten, ins Kino zu kommen.
>
> Ich  habe es kaum erwarten können, ins Kino zu kommen.

The "es" is the object, later expanded as "ins Kino zu kommen".

Finally

> Ich habe viele Lieder gesungen.

No need for "habe gewesen", which by the way is never correct. It's alway "bin gewesen", but in the example it wouldn't make sense.